# Does the destruction of Excalibur mean that the Darkness is now indestructible?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

In *Once Upon A Time*, Emma Swan attempts to destroy the Darkness by means of the sacrifice of Hook and by means of Excalibur.  Unfortunately, Rumplestiltskin sabotages the plan and the Darkness is transferred into him.  Since Excalibur was destroyed, does this mean that the Darkness is now indestructible?

Comment: It’s possible, but doubtful. Don’t forget, there was also the Dark Grail, which was used to take away magic. It is possible that it could be forged into something similar. Prometheus’s coal may be gone, but don’t forget that it was take from the gods to begin with.